# Encounter error while using 'kaiser_fast' in librosa.load

Tags: python, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, wav, librosa

I want to load *.wav files. I am using the following code

```
 audio, sample_rate = librosa.load(file_name, res_type='kaiser_fast', duration=20)
```

However, I get the following error

```
No module named 'resampy'
```

I tried to install resampy and it successfully installed. However, the error did not solve.

I am expecting to use kaise_fast and do not get an error.

Answer (score 0):

just install "resampy" library using:

```
pip install resampy
```

if error exists, report the new error.
I don't have error after installing resampy

Comment: Didn't work for me